# Replacing keyboard command with commands from a list

Tags: python

My group is attempting to create an AI that plays Tetris and is struggling to figure out the right way to replace the part of the code in the original file that executes the keyboard command with one that executes a list of commands that will be passed to it. Below is the original code for this part.

```
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.USEREVENT+1:
                self.drop(False)
            elif event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                self.quit()
            elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                for key in key_actions:
                    if event.key == eval("pygame.K_"
                    +key):
                        key_actions[key]()
```

We have tried a slew of different approaches but none get any reaction from the game and instead cause it to break. Is there a simple way we are missing to do this?

Edit: should add, "key_actions" is a switch statement that takes a string equivalent to the name of a keystroke and executes the proper command. I've tried changing this to take strings from a list with the same names but it has no effect other than causing the game to break if a keystroke is entered.

Answer (score 0):

Using a dictionary pattern is much more interesting in this case (and avoids evil eval):

```
import pygame

def action1():
    print('up')

def action2():
    print('down')

key_actions = {pygame.K_UP : action1,
               pygame.K_DOWN : action2,
               }

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((200,200))

while True:

    for event in pygame.event.get():

        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key in key_actions:
                key_actions[event.key]()
```

EDIT :

This should match the pattern you already have for `key_actions` :

```
kb_keys = {pygame.K_UP : key_actions['UP'],
           pygame.K_DOWN : key_actions['DOWN'],
           }

for event in pygame.event.get():

    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        quit()
    elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

        if event.key in kb_keys:
            kb_keys[event.key]()
```

Comment: @BGrossman i hope the edit is closer from what you looking for